# Is ‘in/of the world’ required after ‘many/several/a lot of/some countries’?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

It is very common in English to use ‘in/of the world’ after expressions such as *many/some/several/a lot of countries*.

Is that necessary?

Because to my ear the word ‘country’ by itself mean a part of the world.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that *of the world* is, strictly speaking, redundant (setting aside some science-fiction scenarios). However, redundancy, as has been pointed out a number of times on this site, is not always a bad thing. Saying *many countries of the world* pragmatically implicates (although it does not logically imply) that the countries in question are scattered around the world, rather than concentrated in a particular region.